# How do I remove the dot when reverting a string using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I need to reverse `Hello.` using recursion so that the end result does not have a `.`

My current method is:

```
public void foo(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(system.in);
    char c = scan.nextChar();
    if (c!='.')
        foo();
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

This seems to output the reverse, however it still has the `.`. Can someone point me in the right direction to get rid of the period?

Comment: Does this compile? You are trying to compare a `char` (`c`) to a `String` (`"."`) using `!=`. They aren't comparable.

Comment: i edited the "."  it was a mistake. my code actually has '.'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `'.'` instead of `"."` since you are comparing a `char`, not a `String`:

```
public void foo(){
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(system.in);
  char c = scan.nextChar();
  if (c != '.') {
    foo();
    System.out.print(c);
  }
}
```

Also note that if it were a `String`, you'd need to use `equals` to do the comparison. `==` or `!=` is used to compare primitive types, such as `char`.

Answer (score 11):

Put the print inside the braces:

```
if (c!='.') {
   foo();
   System.out.print(c);
}
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. There are very few questions I can answer. This was one of them :(

Answer (score 1):

As its a `char` , it has to be `single quotes`, `eg : 'A'`

```
if (c!='.')
  foo();
System.out.print(c);
}
```