# String Reversal Using Recursion w\o parameters

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am being asked to write a recursive method to reverse a string. I have a class named `Sentence` with a private String variable named `text`. Program is run in separate main class by creating `Sentence` object and calling method. I can not change the return type of the method. I have been working on this for a while and getting nowhere. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
public void reverse() {
    if (text.length() <= 1) {
         return;
    }

    Sentence x = new Sentence(text.substring(1));
    recur = text.substring(0, 1); //recur is another String variable I declared
    text =  x.text.concat(recur);
    x.reverse();
}
```

Comment: You know what "recursive" means, do you? Forget it, sorry. I totally read the code wrong.

Comment: @Fildor What's your point? That code snippet is recursive. It even terminates correctly!

Comment: Yes, I know. Forget it. I understood something wrong in the code. But now I realized. Shame on me :)

Comment: You've got a friend [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554430/recursion-homework) with the same task. Maybe you can look at that question. Are you classmates?

Comment: @MattH Think about the order in which you're doing things. You create a new Instance x with n-1 chars and save the first character. Then you concat the n-1 chars and that saved one and THEN you reverse the string of x ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close. As far as I can see this should work if you swap these two lines:

```
text =  x.text.concat(recur);
x.reverse();
```

Also, you should try to come up with meaningful variable names instead of `x` and `recur`. This will make it easier for others (and you!) to understand your code. For example:

```
public void reverse() {
    if (text.length() <= 1)
        return;

    String firstChar = text.substring(0, 1);

    Sentence rest = new Sentence(text.substring(1));
    rest.reverse();

    text = rest.text.concat(firstChar);
}
```